# No Signal from DisplayPort through switch out of USB-C

Tags: displayport, kvm-switch, usb-c

I have the following equipment:

- [Acer Predator Z35P](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/SI/content/predator-model/UM.CZ1EE.P01) (the monitor has a DisplayPort. I don't know why it's not listed as such on their official website)
- [Dell XPS 15 9520](https://www.dell.com/de-de/shop/laptops/xps-15-laptop/spd/xps-15-9520-laptop) with the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti
- [DisplayPort Switch](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B089NH9BL1)
- [DisplayPort Cable](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B012VLL41O)

When I connect my laptop directly via the USB-C to DisplayPort cable to my monitor it works perfectly fine at 3440x1440@120Hz. When I connect my laptop via the same cable to the DisplayPort switch and then have the DisplayPort switch connected to my monitor it only works at 60Hz or lower no matter what resolution I choose. If I choose a higher framerate than 60Hz my monitor shows "No Signal" even if I switch the input in the OSD of the monitor to HDMI and back to DisplayPort.
However when I use my desktop PC which is connected to the same switch on the other input it also works perfectly fine at 3440x1440@120Hz.

I tried switching the DisplayPort cables in the switch inputs but there is no difference: the desktop works and the laptop only at or below 120Hz. I also tried it with another Laptop which has the exact same behavior.

What could be the solution to get my laptop running at 3440x1440@120Hz through the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another DisplayPort to USB-C cable to connect my laptop with the switch an it works now at 3440x1440@120Hz.
I guess the cable wasn't as high quality as it said so it wouldn't work with the increased length and resistance/interference that comes with the switch setup.